# Cantors 2nd Diagonal Argument

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I came across Cantors Diagonal Argument and the uncountability of the interval $(0,1)$. The proof makes sense to me except for one specific detail, which is the following. In the proof it says: Suppose one finds a bijective function $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow (0,1)$, then one can list the numbers of the interval $(0,1)$. I wonder why this is a logical consequence, since obviously it is impossible to write a complete list with all the natural numbers and the corresponding value of $f$. Is this meant to be a consequence under the assumption that it was possible to write out a list that is infinitely long or am I getting something wrong? Even if one had an infinite amount of time one still wouldn't be able to write out a complete list, since it is never complete isn't it? The rest of the proof is clear to me, I've just been asking myself why it is okay to assume one can write out a list like that, since I honestly never asked myself that. Thank you in advance for answers!

Comment: Typically, saying you can list things does not really mean you are actually able to write them out. It is simply a visual way to say that you can view them as elements of a (possibly infinite) sequence indexed by natural numbers, say $\langle a_i, i\in\mathbb{N}\rangle$: eventually, it means no more than pointing out that they are in a bijection with a subset of $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Alright, however if that is the case, then how is the reader supposed to know what exactly the sequence looks like if it's not written out and potentially a non trivial sequence which for example can't be written as a specific expression? Isn't that problematic? I see that there is no problem, if one has a sequence that does have a trivial pattern, but otherwise?

Comment: What you are proving is that there is no bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $(0,1)$ so you don't care about actually building such a bijection. The reasoning is "if you had such a function you would end up in a contradiction, hence you cannot have such a function"

Comment: You're right. What I could do is the following: Suppose f: IN->(0,1), f(n)=an is bijective. Let an_n be the n'th decimal of an. If an_n = 1 let b_n be 2 and if it isn't equal to 1 then let bn be 1. Then the number 0.b_1b_2... will be in (0,1) but not be equal to f(n) for any n , therefore one has a contradiction. Shouldn't this also work? If it does, then this is in my opinion a clearer version of the proof then the one I saw. @LucioTanzini

Comment: Yes @eu271828 this works perfectly